# Will attaching an Adafruit TFT consume/block all the GPIO pins

Tags: peripherals

I'm thinking of picking up this [TFT screen](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Adafruit-Touchscreen-Display-Raspberry-Computer/dp/B00K9THPOQ/ref=pd_ybh_4) for my pi, and can't quite figure out from the images, if it's going to require use of all/some of the GPIO pins on the board, and whether they'll still be accessible for use by jumpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @S.Spieker said it takes only #7 and #11 pin. To get *physical* access to other pins, you may consider using homemeade extender or female-male breadboard cables, so the shield won't cover the rest of unused pins.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon site says:

> Uses the hardware SPI pins (SCK, MOSI, MISO, CE0, CE1) as well as GPIO #25 and #24

SPI Pins: GPIO #7 - #11 - So you can use the other GPIOs.

Comment: Yup, I did spot that, but it's not quite clear (to me) if it's going to connect with a ribbon jumper that will consume all the pins, unless that's more of a however I decide to attach it to the Pi sort of thing?