# Pi 2 Model B, display and TNC-Pi

Tags: hardware

Firstly I am new to the Raspberry world.I have purchased the following and it does not seem like they are compatible pin config and board/hole position. I noticed that the older PI had less PINs for the display but this display says it is compatible.

The main board's hole configuration is not in align with either of the display board or the TNC-Pi board. When the display board is plugged in it is all white and appears to be driver issues. I have tried the Rasbian PI Image from the display manufacture as well as a new Image with custom drivers and configuration I found online. Both same result and I have to reconfigure to use hdmi for it to boot.

Does anyone have any suggestions or corrections to my setup?

- Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Project Board - 1GB RAM - 900 MHz Quad-Core CPU
- TNC-Pi Serial Board http://www.tnc-x.com/TNCPi.htm
- 3.5 inch 320*480 Resistive Touch Screen TFT XPT2046 LCD compatible with Raspberry Pi (Pi 2) Model B B+ A+ Raspbian Video Photo Display System @XYG

[image: My 3 Boards]
[image: Two Stacked with the top board touching the port]

I would really like to get this working for Ham Radio for a Packet Communications setup.

Comment: I was just [looking around](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=TFT%20pins) because I was sure I saw a question recently like this one (about putting a 28-pin TFT on a 40-pin board).  Couldn't find that but I did [find this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=TFT%20pins).  It is odd it does not just work, since the first 28-pins on the 40-pin pin are identical.

Answer (score 2):

Analyze addon board's GPIO connector. If both boards don't have common pins (except 5V, 3V3 or GND of course) you can use this trick: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/23978/21993

Your problem with red board is incredibly easy to solove. Just take electrical tape and insulate the pins on the board, or, even better, stick a piece of tape on the top of ethernet cat5 connector.

You must make sure that the display supports being primary display, ie. if you can tell Pi to output the video signal on the TFT instead of HDMI/RCA.

See here, seems it's the same board: http://ozzmaker.com/enable-x-windows-on-piscreen/
or pi forum here : http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=81022&f=91

Comment: Good answer. I removed "wiki" status from this presuming that was an accident...maybe you thought the button said "kiwi" ;D ?

Comment: Still tinkering in between course work. lol Good suggestions and I think what annoys me the most is the circuit board mount standoffs don't match. I will most likely purchase another board I think the previous model so the pins match up. Will use this board for tinkering.

Comment: @Zippy Well, if you are lucky you can drill holes in the boards so they match with pi's and you don't damage the traces.

Answer (score 1):

I returned this display, seems everyone has the same issue.

Found the manufacture with not support available. 
http://www.wvshare.com/product/3.5inch-RPi-LCD-A.htm